# Python PIL sometimes can't convert ico to png

Tags: python, png, converters, python-imaging-library, ico

I need to convert the favicon with ICO format to PNG. I tried to do it with the PIL:

```
img = Image.open('favicon.ico')
img.save('favicon.png', 'png')
```

But often the conversion was incorrect, since after it favicon not displayed. I was looking for other ways to convert, for example, the PIL has IcoImagePlugin, but I knew he was not to convert. What more way can perform a task?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert an .ICO to .PNG with Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631683/how-to-convert-an-ico-to-png-with-python)

Comment: no, i have a problem what sometimes pil does'nt convert favicon

Comment: Note the comment in the duplicate.  If the ICO contains multiple images, conversion to PNG will appear to fail because PNG is a single-image format.

Comment: i took the advice in dublicate about choosing the size of ico, but it also did'nt help.

Comment: You can only save to PNG if the original ICO contains a single image, or if you extract a single image from the ICO. Otherwise you'll get favicon.png.0, favicon.png.1, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me. 
But PIL is quite old and does not work on python3 so on python3 i'm using the friendly fork: Pillow. 
By the way: it also accepts

```
img.save('favicon.png')
```

Are you sure there is nothing wrong with you favicon ?

Comment: Favicons I take from sites, but in ico they are viewed. I also use the Pillow