# Does anyone know how to convert an ico to a png using python?

Tags: python, png, ico

This is my attempt:

```
import os
from PIL import Image

directory = r'../Icons/ico'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".ico"):
        print(os.path.join(directory, filename))
        img = Image.open(os.path.join(directory,filename))
        sizes = img.info['sizes']
        for i in sizes:
            img.size = i
            print(img.size)
            size_in_string = str(img.size)
            img.save('png/' + filename.strip('.ico') + size_in_string + '.png')
    else:
        continue
```

I'm afraid that this code is not grabbing the separate ico files and instead, grabbing the largest ico file and resizing it. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2):

According to your title.
Here is how to convert a ico to png through python.

```
from PIL import Image
filename = 'image.ico'
img = Image.open(filename)
img.save('image.png')

#Optinally to save with size
icon_sizes = [...]
img.save('image.png', sizes=icon_sizes)
```

I am pretty sure you can adapt it in your code.

Comment: It works prefectly in my machine. Does it throw a particular error?

Comment: It only returns the one size for me, not all of them

Comment: PNG is only capable of representing one image.

Answer (score 0):

you can give a try to :
https://www.convertapi.com/ico-to-png

```
Code snippet is using ConvertAPI Python Client

 
convertapi.api_secret = '<YOUR SECRET HERE>'
convertapi.convert('png', {
    'File': '/path/to/my_file.ico'
}, from_format = 'ico').save_files('/path/to/dir')
```

In addition, we do have a question in stackoverflow.com:
[How to convert an .ICO to .PNG with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631683/how-to-convert-an-ico-to-png-with-python)

Answer (score -1):

or you can just change the end of the .ico file to .png

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).